# I am getting problem in uninstalling an extension from my Vs Code

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am a new user to vs code so I had just installed an extension but don't know how to delete it, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the extensions menu, search for the name of said extension and you will see an uninstall button